# Background image on a page displayed in web browser control doesn't stretch/fit - Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm building an app with a web browser control, which contains a mobile platform-customized page. The background image on that page should automatically fit to the window. And it does when visiting the URL in the ordinary browser. But when showing the page in the web browser control it doesn't fit the web browser window.

The web browser control matches the screen size. Scripts i set to allowed on the control. The WebView for android shows the page correctly.

[image]

Comment: Can you write the url to the image? (and so, we can attach it to your question)

Comment: http://s18.postimage.org/u4q5sd9tl/WPScreen_Bg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I App.xaml.cs of your App you have to comment

```
  //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true
  //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true
  //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true
```

And you will find this in public App().